# can't write to file created with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile

Tags: python, windows, path, file-permissions

I am trying to save an image in Python using Opencv's imwrite. The image name is randomized using tempfile library. But the image is not getting saved as it throws the error

> "[ WARN:1@423.481] global
> D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp
> (773) cv::imwrite_
> imwrite_('C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Temp\Compare_2ia3ttp7.png'):
> can't open file for writing: permission denied".

```
   def contourConversion(imgToNegative, B, G, R):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgToNegative, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)
    # Finding Contours
    # Use a copy of the image e.g. edged.copy()
    # since findContours alters the image
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    counOut_img = cv2.drawContours(imgToNegative, contours, -1, (B, G, R), 2)
    return counOut_img

#Master Image is in Red Countours
#Testing Image is in Purple Countours 

MasterConverted = contourConversion(perfect_img, 0, 0, 255)
TestingConverted = contourConversion(test_img, 255, 0, 255)

Out_img_final = cv2.addWeighted(MasterConverted, 0.4,TestingConverted, 0.4, 0)   

tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png",prefix="Compare_")
#var_name = tf.name
#path = "C:\\Users\\Max\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\CanspiritInternship\\autocamera"
cv2.imwrite(tf.name, Out_img_final)

#cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , tf.name),Out_img_final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.imwrite("ContourComparison.png",Out_img_final)
```

Comment: did you try to write to another folder ?

Comment: please take the [tour] and review [mre]. a good MRE would have tested writability using plain python functions, to exclude OpenCV as the cause.

Answer (score 0):

`NamedTemporaryFile` **opened the file already** and keeps a handle on it:

```
tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png",prefix="Compare_")
```

You can't (ordinarily) open the same file for writing twice.

You are trying to open it **again** (with `imwrite`), which is supposed to fail because the file is **still open** from the `NamedTemporaryFile` call.

---

`%LOCALAPPDATA%` (`Appdata\Local`) is user-writable. `Appdata\Local\Temp` specifically is writable by the user. That is its whole purpose.

`%APPDATA%` (`Appdata\Roaming`) appears to be writable as well (tested on Win10). The system does not prevent apps from messing with each other, or you with that data.

These directories exist *for every user of the system* (and not just that). You are only allowed to touch those that are in your *own* user profile.

Answer (score -1):

You need admin access in Windows to do anything in AppData. Best thing to do would be to just write the image somewhere else.

Above solution would be preferable, but otherwise you may be able to run Python as administrator - not sure if that will work, but give it a go.

Comment: Sometimes you also need to close the file on Windows (if you have the image open, it cannot be overwritten).

Comment: *admin* access? **not** for `AppData\Local\Temp`. the user has full privileges in that directory. -- advising people to run anything as admin just for fun is generally bad advice.

Comment: It certainly does seem like you need administrator permission. Tested by trying to save a text file or create a folder in AppData\Local\Temp, and I get the 'you don't have permission' error. Running text editor as administrator allows me to save in that folder.

Comment: if you can't write to `appdata\local\temp`, you're in someone else's directory, not your own. its whole purpose is to be writable by the current user.

Comment: Ah, I was testing in the 'Default' directory in Users